# Extract viewBox attribute value from SVG string using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, svg

I have the fallowing string:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 18"><title>A</title><path d="M0,18V4A3.83,3.83,0,0,1,1.19,1.18,3.85,3.85,0,0,1,4,0H8a3.81,3.81,0,0,1,2.8,1.19A3.85,3.85,0,0,1,12,4V18H8V10H4v8ZM4,8H8V4A2,2,0,0,0,6,2a1.92,1.92,0,0,0-1.4.59A1.92,1.92,0,0,0,4,4Z"/></svg>
```

I would like to retrieve value from view box:

```
"0 0 12 18"
```

What I have so far:

```
/"\d\s\d\s\d\d\s\d\d"/
```

As you can see this does not guarantee that extracted value will be viewBox, plus it does not cover situation when values are not single digit, like so: 123 32 1239 33

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) - don't use regex, use a parser

Comment: @Jan that was way too fast of a response to my comment...

Comment: @ctwheels: Honestly I stopped reading a regex question starting with `<...`. I did wait for the pony link by you, though :)

Comment: Thanks but I need to be lib free

Comment: @jan Yeah man! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser since it's not wise to use RegExp on XML / HTML

```js
const myString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 18"><title>A</title><path d="M0,18V4A3.83,3.83,0,0,1,1.19,1.18,3.85,3.85,0,0,1,4,0H8a3.81,3.81,0,0,1,2.8,1.19A3.85,3.85,0,0,1,12,4V18H8V10H4v8ZM4,8H8V4A2,2,0,0,0,6,2a1.92,1.92,0,0,0-1.4.59A1.92,1.92,0,0,0,4,4Z"/></svg>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(myString, "text/html");

console.log( doc.querySelector("svg").getAttribute("viewBox") ); // "0 0 12 18"
```

The *Why not use RegExp to parse?* can be *illustrated* by the simple fact that DOM is extremely permissive, attributes (i.e: like `data-*`) are not restrictive on it's content (just think of i.e: `data-cont="<b data-cont='<b'></b>"`), etc etc... imagine the unsustainable regex nightmare you should write. And you'd never get it right.

**Regex** ...for the *"I know my string, man!"* moments:

```js
const myString = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 18"><title>A</title><path d="M0,18V4A3.83,3.83,0,0,1,1.19,1.18,3.85,3.85,0,0,1,4,0H8a3.81,3.81,0,0,1,2.8,1.19A3.85,3.85,0,0,1,12,4V18H8V10H4v8ZM4,8H8V4A2,2,0,0,0,6,2a1.92,1.92,0,0,0-1.4.59A1.92,1.92,0,0,0,4,4Z"/></svg>`;

const viewBox = (/viewBox="([^"]+)"/.exec(myString)||'')[1] ;
console.log( viewBox )  // "0 0 12 18" or undefined (if not found)
```

Comment: Fair point on why not to use regex for html/xml parse. I will make this one accepted for the sake of the rest of the community, but as @Jan mentioned it is also ok to use regex for small "htm/xml/svg" chunks such as mine, because I'm sure that I will get this data and nothing else, since program I'm writing depend on such structure.

Comment: This has been a discussion for ages and it won't stop anywhere soon. I did vote for your approach as well but honestly, attributes like `data-cont="viewBox=..."` are very rare in reality.

Answer (score 2):

Just use getAttribute and split by whitespaces or comma.  According to MDN, it could be whitespaces or comma that separates the values.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/viewBox

```
    let svg_canvas = document.getElementById('svg_canvas');
    let viewBox = svg_canvas.getAttribute('viewBox');
    let view_box_attr = viewBox.split(' '); //whitespace or comma

    //min-x, min-y, width and height
    //the values are string so need to parse
    let zoom_factor = 1;
    let minx = parseInt(view_box_attr[0]) + zoom_factor;
    let miny = parseInt(view_box_attr[1]) + zoom_factor;
    let width = parseInt(view_box_attr[2])- zoom_factor;
    let height = parseInt(view_box_attr[3]) - zoom_factor;
    let newViewBox =  minx+" "+miny+" "+width+" "+height;
    console.log('old '+viewBox+' new '+newViewBox);
    svg_canvas.setAttribute( 'viewBox', newViewBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, you can analyze short and simple `XML/HTML/SVG` sequences with regular expressions. In your case this could be

```
viewBox="([^"]+)"
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/DGKhxF/1) and the following snippet:

```js
var svg = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 12 18"><title>A</title><path d="M0,18V4A3.83,3.83,0,0,1,1.19,1.18,3.85,3.85,0,0,1,4,0H8a3.81,3.81,0,0,1,2.8,1.19A3.85,3.85,0,0,1,12,4V18H8V10H4v8ZM4,8H8V4A2,2,0,0,0,6,2a1.92,1.92,0,0,0-1.4.59A1.92,1.92,0,0,0,4,4Z"/></svg>'

var match = svg.match(/viewBox="([^"]+)"/)
console.log(match[1])
```

However, it is not advisable...

Comment: Why wouldn't be advisable? And would using DOMParser make things faster? And thx btw.

Comment: @NikolaMitic: No, a regex is usually faster but a parser is safer.

Comment: @NikolaMitic please click on the link I posted in the comments. HTML is not regular language (which is why Jan mentions it's *not advisable*).

Comment: @ctwheels: Despite being very popular, unfortunately, the answer you linked to, does not explain very much as to **why** you shouldn't do it.

Comment: Fair enough, @NikolaMitic see [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

Comment: @ctwheels: Imo, this is a more realistic view - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1733489#1733489

Comment: @all thanks, just had a look at it while you guys had discussion here. The thing is that I'm sure that my svgs are going to be small ones, just like at that url answer Jan posted. Regex would be faster solution and with not having much to parse,I think it is safe to go with regex here, your final thoughts, before I choose accepted answer? :D

Comment: @NikolaMitic: In this case, a regular expression solution might very well work - though Roko's answer feels more like the "right approach".

Comment: @Jan all right, I agree. I will choose his one (for the sake of the rest of the community), but will go with regex for my case, but also gonna post comment on his answer referring to use of regex  , thank you.